# Python Partition string based on input

Tags: python, string, parsing

I want to have Python partition a string up until a certain character. That character (a mathematical operator; `+, -, /, or x`) will be defined by the user through input. For example, if the user inputs `"Cheese+Bacon"`, it should give me `["Cheese", "+", "Bacon"]`. But if the user inputs ``"Cheese-Bacon", it would give me `["Cheese", "-", "Bacon"]`, and same goes for the other two operators.  I have this code, but obviously .partition cannot read since it is a list. How could I go about doing this?

```
operators = ['+', '-', '/', 'x']
for ops in operators:
    disGet.partition(operators)
```

disGet is a reference to display.get(), which is an Entry widget in Tkinter which is where the player inputs.

Comment: How do you want to partition `'Cheese x Bacon'` ?  What about `'Tex-Mex with bacon'`?

Comment: Well in reality the code is for a calculator so the input is mostly integers, therefore reocurring operator signs like X in words shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go the regular expression route, just test to see whether each partition operation worked, and break when one of them does:

```
disGet = "cheese-bacon"
operators = '+-/x'

for op in operators:
    part = disGet.partition(op)
    if part[1]:    # contains the partitioning string on success, empty on failure
        break
else:              # nothing worked, so do whatevs
     part = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use list splicing.

```
>>> s = "Cheese+Bacon"
>>> op = '+'
>>> x = [s.split(op)[0]] + [op] + [s.split(op)[-1]]
>>> x
['Cheese', '+', 'Bacon']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the string once and do a lookup for each op and just pull the string spliced if you get a match:

```
operators = {'+', '-', '/', 'x'}

s = "Cheese-Bacon"

out = next(([s[:i], ch, s[i+1:]] for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in operators), None)
if out:
    # do whatever
```

If you want to get multiple operators:

```
def split_keep_sep(s, ops):
    inds = ((i, ch) for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in ops)
    prev = 0
    for i, ch in inds:
        yield s[prev:i]
        yield ch
        prev = i + 1
   yield s[i+1:]
```

Demo:

```
In [26]: operators = {'+', '-', '/', 'x'}

In [27]: s = "cheese+bacon-patty/lettuce?"

In [28]: print(list(split_keep_sep(s, operators)))
['cheese', '+', 'bacon', '-', 'patty', '/', 'lettuce?']
```

Comment: This works really well, do you know if there's any way to have this account for more than one operator? Say if I were to do "cheese+bacon-patty/lettuce?"

Comment: If you want it to work for more than just the first then keep calling iterating over  `out = (([s[:i], ch, s[i+1:]] for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in operators), None)`, tile you hit None, you can also just keep calling `next(out...

Comment: @stack.tm, I added a function that will split on multiple delimiters